# javascript undefined errors on some of the fields

Tags: javascript

All of a sudden, I get undefined errors in JavaScript.

```
Error: TypeError: document.userForm.surname is undefined
```

I get the error when I try to call the value of a form field. The funny thing is that some of the fields returns a type of string while others return undefined, however they are all declared the same and are of the same input type etc... I am totally clueless at this point and seek the knowledge of the stack-overflow gods to assist me.

Here is a section of the page to show you that the values return successfully from the database and fill the fields on the form:

[image: edit user]

Here is the section of the form that is displayed above and also the button where I call the javascript:

```
<form class=\"gideonform\" name=\"userForm\">
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\">Password: </td>
    <td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"   maxlength=\"50\" type=\"password\" name=\"password\" value=".$dbuserpassword."></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\"></td>
    <td id=\"left\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\">Title: </td>
    <td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"   maxlength=\"5\" type=\"text\" name=\"title\" value=\"".$dbusertitle."\"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\"></td>
    <td id=\"left\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\">Name: </td>
    <td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"   maxlength=\"50\" type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"".$dbusername."\"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\"></td>
    <td id=\"left\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\">Surname: </td>
    <td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"   maxlength=\"50\" type=\"text\" name=\"surname\" value=\"".$dbusersurname."\"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\"></td>
    <td id=\"left\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id=\"right\">Date of Birth: </td>
    <td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"   maxlength=\"50\" type=\"text\" name=\"dateofbirth\" id=\"dateofbirth\" value=\"".$dbuserdateofbirth."\"></input></td>
</tr>
<td id=\"left\"><input size=\"50\"  type=\"button\" id=\"button\" name=\"btnsubmit\" onClick=\"function1();\"  value=\"                 Save                  \"/></td>
```

And here is the line in the JavaScript file where I get the error:

```
name            :   document.userForm.name.value,
surname         :   document.userForm.surname.value,
title           :   document.userForm.title.value,
```

only name and title has a type of string, all the other fields are undefined. This is extremely weird for me because I use this exact code all over my project and it works fine.

Comment: notes: 1) you better use single quote, so that the code doesn't look so horrible. 2) you have to escape the values for the input forms. 3) you have to provide a code which reproduces the problem 4) please don't post PHP code if it's not relevant. Copy the output from your browser, so it's plain HTML.

Comment: try removing back slashes ("\"), also there is no form end tag "</form>"

Comment: You're also repeating the IDs `right` and `left`. Although this may not have any effect on your form or script, it's invalid HTML and you should change them to classes. `name` and `title` are working because they are reserved words within the HTML spec.

Comment: thx for all the comments, I will have a look and report back, I am also busy converting all those id's to classes. And the reason you see no end tag for the form is because I only posted a small section of the code, anyway, Ill go fiddle with the code and let you know.

Comment: @Janpan: Don't post "a small section of the code" - make the _whole script_ smaller for debugging and post _all_ of that _smaller_ script.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to do this is

- considered obsolete for god knows how long and
- not cross-browser (but I'm not sure)

Better way would be to get the elements using `getElementById`:

```
name : document.getElementById('surname').value
```

Don't forget to assign `id` attributes to the form, e.g.

```
<input name=\"surname\" id='surname' ...>
```

Refer to [`getElementById` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) for details.

Comment: Does (for example) `name="surname"` require backslashes?

Comment: Thx, I will go look at the code and let you know shortly what happened.

Comment: @suspectus no, but it should not have any effect on that.

Comment: @Janpan, omg, why do you put the whole form in an echo? `PHP` is a template engine itself, so everything it does not recognize as php code is just outputted to the page.

Comment: @J0HN , I tried using the getElementById method and just got null values. I have a feeling my form does not go into a ready state or something ?

Comment: @J0HN , the reason the whole form is inside an echo is because it is part of a php if statement, e.g. if there is such a user, echo the details, else echo that no such user exists.

Comment: @Janpan what do you mean by "ready" state? There's no such thing. As of the form in echo - I would move this code into separate file and than just include it. And anyway, you don't have to `echo` it even in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with adding `\` before `"` due to this you are getting error, otherwise it is working fine look for below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YVf3D/

Comment: Also remove from form name <form class=\"gideonform\" name="userForm">

Comment: stil the same issues.

Comment: It should work, provide your jsfiddle so we can help you out.